# Issue Fetching API Data with React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, components, jsx

I'm working on a simple React web app and I'm having problem viewing certain data I'm pulling from this mock api: https://randomuser.me/api/

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ApiTest extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        names: [],
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
  .then(results => {
    return results.json();
  }).then(data => {
    let names = data.results.map((name) => {
      return(
        <div key={name.results}>
           {name.title}
        </div>
      )
    })
    this.setState({names: names});
    console.log("state", this.state.names);
  })
}

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">

          <div className="container2">
            <div className="container1">
              {this.state.names}   
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default ApiTest;
```

I am able to pull in the pictures based off the tutorial I found for all of this (https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2) but I can't seem to get anything else to display. I don't seem to be getting any errors and I see these objects in the console. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's really not a very good idea to put jsx into your component state. State should consist of plain data. Then you can transform you data in a flexible manner inside `render()` function:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qqy9l78l06

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ApiTest extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ people: data.results }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container2">
          <div className="container1">

            {this.state.people.map(person => (
              <div>{person.name.first}</div>
            ))}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ApiTest;
```

Comment: Is this why you separated the code into .js and .jsx files? Thanks! this seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Hi! No separation has nothing to do with the fact that it works :-) Actually on codesandbox .js and .jsx files are equaly, but usually only .jsx files are expected to have jsx code in them.

Comment: I tick'd it but I guess if you have less than 15 rep it doesn't visually change. Thanks for your help!